# Ajax with RequestDispatcher not working

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I've made a form in JSP say first.jsp

```
    <input type="radio" name="actionType" value="edit_notice" class="noticeaction">Edit 
    <input type="radio" name="actionType" value="delete_notice" class="noticeaction">Delete 
    <input type="radio" name="actionType" value="post_notice" class="noticeaction">Post Notice 
    <br/><br/><br/>

    <input type="submit" name="reviewNoticeSubmit" value="Submit" id="reviewNoticeSubmit">
```

The jQuery in which the ajax call is:

```
else if(actionToPerform == "edit_notice")
            {
                var noticeId = $(".selectednotice").val();
                var param = "noticeId=" + noticeId;

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url : "reviewnoticeaction/editnotice",
                    data : param,
                    beforeSend : function() {

                    },
                    complete : function() {

                    },
                    success : function(data) {

                    },
                    error : function(xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("Error occured. Unable to open editor");
                    }

                });

            }
```

The below is the servlet code getting some value from the database and assigning to attributes and I'm trying to forward it to another jsp page. It is not working.

```
request.setAttribute("firstData", editNoticeRs.getString("firstData"));
                    request.setAttribute("secondData", editNoticeRs.getDate("secondData"));
                    request.setAttribute("thirdData", editNoticeRs.getDate("thirdData"));

RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("second.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
```

**PS:** In case if I can't forward it to another jsp is it possible to get the values in the same jsp page and access the value? If yes how?

Comment: The jquery `ajax` method is an HTTP client in its own right. It can send requests and receive responses. The responses it receives are unrelated to the browser page you are currently looking at.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to dispatch to a JSP from your servlet for Ajax. Just doing everything in the servlet will be simpler. And yes, in Ajax you can read the output from the servlet. That's what the "data" variable in your success function is for.

```
 success : function(data) {
   alert(data);
 },
```

Of course you can still dispatch to a JSP from your servlet if you want. Probably the reason why it seems to not be working is you are doing nothing with the returned output.

Comment: Thanks @developerwjk, I want to know how to set the value for the variable "data" in the success method. What should I do in the servlet to get the values I desired to get in data(at present my data variable is empty).

Comment: I have posted as an answer how to return data from servlet

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return JSON or String datat back to ajax success handler from servlet simple call the

```
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
out.println("String Data to return");
```

or if it is json

```
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder()
data.append("{");
data.append("'name':");
data.append("'arock',");
data.append("'Language':");
data.append("'Java'");
data.append("}");
out.println(data.toString());
```